# fit webpage content on a fixed size iframe

Tags: javascript, html, css, ajax, iframe

Is there any javascript, ajax, css or any other method to get a webpage content fitted on a fixed widht iframe? Like mobile device browser does. Thank you.

Comment: check out overflow:hidden; CSS definition

Comment: this property hides scroll bars but not fit content into a fixed width iframe

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You define a container div with a fixed width (say 400px) and set that div to overflow hidden. That will force the content of that div to stay within the 400px width. You put all the content that you want to have in the iframe in that container div. And then, you put that div inside the iframe.

I think that'd be the easiest way to do it.

Comment: I agree but I mean an external website, so we do not have control through its code to set div width.

Comment: I don't understand: you own the inner content of the iframe or the site that's holding the iframe?

Comment: sorry, site that's holding the iframe

Comment: Then same technique: you put the iframe inside a container div of a certain width with overflow set to hidden. That way, if the iframe overflows, the container div will restrict it.